# 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.] when firing event from LightningModal according to the documentation

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, modal

I'm trying to use the lightning modal component described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation).

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<lightning-modal-footer>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={labels.GlobalDeploy} onclick={handleDeploy}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="neutral" label={labels.GlobalCancel} onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
</lightning-modal-footer>

import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class EditSbcFieldSetMappingModal extends LightningModal {

   handleDeploy() {
     var { recordTypeName }  = this.currentFieldSetMetadata; 

     var payload = {
        detail: {
            'recordTypeName':recordTypeName,
            'userProfileName':this.userProfileName,
            'accountFieldSetName':'',
            'accountAddressFieldSetName':'',
            'addressFieldSetName':''
        }
     };
     var ev = new CustomEvent('changemetadata',payload)
     console.log(ev);
     this.dispatchEvent(ev);
 }
```

But when I click the button I get

> [Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.]

I'm opening the modal as described in the doc like this

```
editFieldSetMappingModal.open({
    label:`Edit Fieldsets`,
    size:'large',
    description: 'Modal Title with brief description',
    onchangemetadata: (e) => {
        // stop further propagation of the event
        e.stopPropagation();
        // hand off to separate function to process
        // result of the event (see above in this example)
        this.handleDeployMdtEvent(e.detail);
        // or proxy to be handled above by dispatching
        // another custom event to pass on the event
        // this.dispatchEvent(e);
    },
    options:[
        {...currentFieldSetMetadata},
        this.selectedUserProfile,
        recordTypeLabel,
        true
    ]
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Here's how they recomended to do it:

```
// Trigger visibility of the modal
handleOpenModal() {
  MyModal.open({
    label: 'Modal Title',
    size: 'large',
    description: 'Modal Title with brief description',
    // event triggered when new CustomEvent('select', {detail: {}});
    // occurs *from within* LightningModal.
    // see dispatchSelectEvent() in c/myModal.js above
    onselect: (e) => {
      // stop further propagation of the event
      e.stopPropagation();
      // hand off to separate function to process
      // result of the event (see above in this example)
      this.handleSelectEvent(e.detail);
      // or proxy to be handled above by dispatching
      // another custom event to pass on the event
      // this.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
  });
 }
```

Am I missing something ??

Comment: Hi @SallyRothroat, for clarity, is the error being thrown by the modal component or the component that is encapsulating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, and we have a bug logged that we may or may not resolve in upcoming releases. May not because LWR security is the future and eventually every org will have to turn on the LWR security setting.

1. To solve it, the easiest is if your org can have Lightning Web Security setting in the Session settings [enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable). Before enabling this, make sure all of your LWC components and Aura components work fine by manually testing it.
2. If you decided to have LWS disabled due to needing more time to test through your components, there is a workaround.

Wrap your buttons used in the footer with a child component like below

**deployButton.html**

```
    <lightning-button variant="brand" 
                      label={labels.GlobalDeploy}
                      onclick={handleDeploy}>
    </lightning-button>
```

**deployButton.js**

```
handleDeploy() {
 @api data;

 var payload = {
    detail: {
        data
    }
 };
 var ev = new CustomEvent('changemetadata',payload)
 console.log(ev);
 this.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Modify your Modal component to use the Wrapper

**html**

```
<lightning-modal-footer>
<c-deploy-button data={data}></c-deploy-buttonn>
<lightning-button variant="neutral" label={labels.GlobalCancel} onchangemetadata={closeModal}></lightning-button>
```

Make sure to have `data` populated and passed from the javascript.

Comment: Excellent! thank you

Answer (score 2):

This answer is Mohith's workaround, the only one to work here, however I needed to generalize the workaround by creating an lwc called eventPasser:

eventPasser.js

```js
// WORK AROUND for issue with LWC extending and legacy Lightning Locker
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class EventPasser extends LightningElement {

    @api 
    passEvent(event) {
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

eventPasser.html

```html
<template></template>
```

I use it by adding it to the troubled lwcs' html and replacing typical `this.dispatchEvent` js:

```html
<c-event-passer></c-event-passer>
```

```js
const passer = this.template.querySelector('c-event-passer');
passer.passEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {
    bubbles: true,
    composed: true,
    detail,
}));
```

Comment: Love the generalization!  thank you.